# A double pointer keeping track of all the words appearing on a sentence

Tags: c, split, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

1. Double pointer holding the words from a sentence.
2. Why my code won't work even when after a lot of brainstorming, I am failing to understand.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char *str_orig = "abcd efgh ijklm";
    char **holder = NULL;
    int point = 0, ppoint = 0;
    int word_count = 0;
    while (str_orig[point]!='\0'){
        if(str_orig[point]==' '){
            word_count++;
        if(holder==NULL)
            holder = (char**) calloc (1,sizeof(char*));
        else
            holder = (char**) realloc (holder, word_count*sizeof(char*));    
        char* strnghold =  (char*) calloc ((point-ppoint + 1),sizeof(char));
        while(ppoint < point){
            strnghold[ppoint] = str_orig[ppoint];
            ppoint++;
        }
        ppoint++;
        holder[word_count - 1] = strnghold;
        }
        point++; 
    }
    printf(holder[0]); //prints "abcd\0"
    printf(holder[1]); //prints Nothing, care to explain???
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? Also, this looks like c, and not c++.

Comment: Not able to store the next word successfully in the double-pointer char variable. Yeah it's C.

Comment: Don't brainstorm, use your debugger.

Comment: No need for `if(holder == NULL)`.  You can pass NULL as the first argument to realloc, and it behaves as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, still a beginner. :)

Comment: regarding; `printf(holder[0]);` and `printf(holder[1]);`  These statements do not cleanly compile!  Please read the MAN page for `printf()` and note the syntax, and compare that syntax to what you have written.

Comment: OT: regarding; `holder = (char**) realloc (holder, word_count*sizeof(char*)); `  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) when calling `realloc()`, always assign the result to a 'temp' pointer, then check that 'temp' for NULL,  ONLY if not NULL then copy the 'temp' pointer to the target pointer.  Other wise there will be an unrecoverable memory leak

Comment: OT:  regarding: `char* strnghold =  (char*) calloc ((point-ppoint + 1),sizeof(char));`  1) see comment (above) about `realloc()` and casting.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value

Comment: the posted code seems to be trying to generate a 2 dimensional array, in which the first dimension is any array of pointers and the second dimension contains a single word.  However, that is not what the posted code is actually doing.

Comment: to use `printf()` to output an array of characters, (I.E. a single word) it is best to terminate each array with a NUL character (0x00) then the call to `printf()` would look similar to: `for( size_t i = 0; i < wordCount; i++ ) { printf( "%s\n", holder[i] ); }`

Answer (score 0):

This while loop

```
    while(ppoint < point){
        strnghold[ppoint] = str_orig[ppoint];
        ppoint++;
    }
    ppoint++;
```

invokes undefined behavior when `ppoint` is not equal to 0 because this expression `strnghold[ppoint]` can access memory beyond the allocated memory pointed to by `strnghold`.

You can get the expected result if to substitute the while loop for the for loop like

```
    for ( int i = ppoint; ppoint < point; ppoint++ ){
        strnghold[ppoint - i] = str_orig[ppoint];
    }
    ppoint++;
```

However pay attention to that the last word will not be processed because the string does not contain a trailing space.

And you should free the allocated memory before exiting the program.

But in any case the approach is unsafe because a string can contain adjacent  spaces or have for example several leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the help, got the issue. Arigato.